# Cannot find web elements at "chrome://downloads/" page

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Java and Selenium to write tests for Chrome. Sometimes I need to get to `chrome://downloads/` and click on `CLEAR ALL` button. I can get to the page by

```
RemoteWebDriver driver = (RemoteWebDriver) driverChrome;
        driver.executeScript("window.open();");
        Thread.sleep(500);
        tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driverChrome.getWindowHandles());
        driverChrome.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
        Thread.sleep(500);
        driverChrome.get("chrome://downloads/");
```

but I cannot click on the button, whatever xpath I use it says `no such element`

Comment: What about just searching for it by button text?

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? You mention using XPATH but you never gave any examples.

Answer (score 2):

Below here `JavascriptExecutor` example to perform click on `CLEAR ALL` button using selenium :-

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver
executor.executeScript("var dm = document.getElementsByTagName('downloads-manager')[0];var toolbar = dm.shadowRoot.getElementById('toolbar');var actions = toolbar.shadowRoot.getElementById('actions');actions.getElementsByClassName('clear-all')[0].click();");
```

Tested in `Chrome Version 50.0.2661.102 m`

Hope it will help you..:)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I need to know the reason and how to create those javascript snippet codes

Comment: Here is some spacial html tag are used like downloads-manager.. without switching to this downloads-manager we can not find the clear all button by normal xpath, cssSelector etc. In selenium we can switch to window,frame and then locate the element but there is no any concept to switch downloads-manager which works as like frame.. so that's why selenium introduced JavascriptExecutor  where we can write our own java script and execute for automation.

Comment: If you seriously want to know how to create javascript snippet, it's very simple just inspect the element on browser by pressing f12 which you want to locate and examine how to find a right way to automate..you can write your javascript  and run on browser console and ensure your javascript is working fine or not.